# Is it okay if we do not cleanup the side effects in react useEffect

Tags: reactjs

React useEffect is used for side effects and they should be cleared or else we get warnings like memory leaks. This means all the setTimeout should be cleared. But if you see the code below, I have commented the clearTimeout in useEffect in the Home component and now when I navigate to other route, there is no warning.

What is the right way?

[Here is the link to code](https://codesandbox.io/s/3jnmpw)

Comment: React 18 [removes these warnings](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#react) since more often than not they aren't a big deal. A setTimeout is only going to run at most once so if you don't actually need it, it's probably not critical to cancel. A setInterval would be a different story. Also your link to code does not link to code, *and* your code should be in the question itself not off site

Comment: @BrianThompson Thank you for the quick reply. I have updated the link to the code. Check it in case you want to have a look at the code. Next time onwards, I will post the code in the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not okay!

It's true that in React 18 they removed the in-famous warning that everybody received at least once:

> *Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.*

Here are explained the reasons why they removed this warning in React 18: https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/82

Basically, you need to use common sense, if you are attaching event listeners, websocket listeners, or saving intervals on memory, it's important you remember to clear them on unmount or you are ending up with memory leaks. They removed thw warn since it triggered the warning that you were updating state on an unmounted component, if you were trying to perform an async operation with a setState, after the component had already unmounted. That's a common scenario and to avoid that warn you need to place flags inside the useEffect to check if the component is still mounted at the moment to execute the async setState. That was bloating the code, since most effects do not need a clear function, but people had to add the `isMounted = false` flag on `return` so to have a boolean control inside the useEffect.  But that definitely is not that important since it doesn't cause a memory leak trying to update the state of an unmounted component...

So they preferred to remove that warn, but that does not mean you must not care to clear the above mentioned stuff. Always clear up timeouts, intervals, raf, subscriptions, and event listeners!

EDIT: As per @Brian Thompson suggestion, it's not mandatory to clear timeouts if they are not used recursively since they'll execute just once.

Comment: How is failing to clear a timeout that sets state any different than failing to cancel a state update after say a fetch request? Both will try to set state unnecessarily at most one time.  The real risk of memory leaks are the situations in your answer like subscriptions, intervals, etc that will continue to run indefinitely even though the component is unmounted.

Comment: You forget that timeouts are often used recursively, instead of raf, for example in animations, that's why it's a good practice to clear them... Obviously it's a matter of common sense, if it's a one time timeout, it's not that important ...

Comment: I don't know about *often*, but technically that is true that a recursive timeout would need to be cleared. This is not the OP's use-case though. I would agree that the final answer is to use common sense. But I still believe very strongly that in 99% of cases this no-op is not an actual issue. It would seem that React agrees since they are removing the warning.

Comment: @Brian Thompson Initially OP linked a demo of a clock , without source code, since he said he was using setTimeout, I assumed he was using a recursive timeout, since it's the best way to have a more accurated clock in JS. He only later updated the question with source code, showing he is using useEffect dep to reexecute the timeout (  I don't think that's a good idea, since you will probably add some extra delay ), so in his particular case it's safe not to clear, yes you are right.